# ks.getKieClasspathContainer() throwing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, android-studio, drools

I've been trying to integrate the Drools ecosystem in my rudimentary Android application.
So far, I have been able to integrate all the required Drools libraries and I have also implemented a short Drools algorithm based on the Drools HelloWorld example.

Somehow, I am still encountering an issue in the following lines:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
```

`ks` is being instanciated, but when we get to `ks.getKieClasspathContainer()`, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

In debug mode, I have also been able to see the following details concerning the exception:

```
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Details: http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema
```

Here is my `DroolsTest.java` file:

```
public class DroolsTest {

    public static  void test() {
        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

            Purchase cashPurchase = new Purchase("john", 150, PaymentMethod.CASH);
            Purchase debitPurchase = new Purchase("peter", 200, PaymentMethod.DEBIT);
            Purchase creditPurchase = new Purchase("george", 300, PaymentMethod.CREDIT);

            kSession.insert(cashPurchase);
            kSession.insert(debitPurchase);
            kSession.insert(creditPurchase);

            kSession.fireAllRules();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", "error in drools");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void rules(View view){
        DroolsTest.test();
    }
}
```

The `rules()` function in `MainActivity` is called when I click on an OK button in my interface.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Much appreciated.

**ETA:**
You can find the entire code on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeanineharb/DroolsTest).

**ETA:**
Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$kModuleMarshaller.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:189)
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:139)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:163)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:125)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:96)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:68)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.<init>(KieContainerImpl.java:84)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:83)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:66)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:57)
        at com.example.jeanineharb.myapplication.DroolsTest.test(DroolsTest.java:15)
        at com.example.jeanineharb.myapplication.MainActivity.rules(MainActivity.java:40)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:192)
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$KieModuleValidator.loadSchema(KieModuleModelImpl.java:236)
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$KieModuleValidator.<clinit>(KieModuleModelImpl.java:233)
            at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$kModuleMarshaller.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:189)
            at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:139)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:163)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:125)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:96)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:68)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.<init>(KieContainerImpl.java:84)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:83)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:66)
            at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:57)
            at com.example.jeanineharb.myapplication.DroolsTest.test(DroolsTest.java:15)
            at com.example.jeanineharb.myapplication.MainActivity.rules(MainActivity.java:40)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**NB:**
I'm using Drools v6.2.0.

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without a full stack dump, or at least the exact line where that exception is thrown, together with the Drools version.

Comment: @laune Thanks for your comment. I have edited my post to include the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the code in the KieModuleImpl trying to get an object of the class `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory`, i.e., the one for loading an XML Schema factory for that Schema language. Make sure to have some library in the classpath where that class can be found. (To check, run this simple code:

```
SchemaFactory factory =
  SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
System.out.println( factory.getClass() );
```

But it may be possible to avoid `KieContainer` altogether and build from a `KieFileSystem` into which the (presumably) DRL resource(s) is (are) copied. Did you try this yet?

Comment: This code is throwing another `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Should I add some library to the project?

I'm still new to Drools, so I haven't tried the `KieFileSystem` yet. I will look into it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure you can run your `DroolsTest`code from the Linux command line/shell script (or via a Windows bat) so you have full control over all libraries. I can help you with the former if necessary - but it's very simple.